# abs representation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Do these brackets represent absolute value highlighted yellow below? These are equations for fault detection on sensor data for analysis in HVAC system operation.

[image]

Comment: Unless something really weird is going on, then yes that is an absolute value. Interestingly, there seems to be a typo on the other side of the inequality. I imagine they meant: $\sqrt{\varepsilon\mathrm{MAT}^2+\varepsilon\mathrm{OAT}^2}$.

Comment: Ah yes I didnt even see that typo, ha. Thanks for the tip I will hit the green check if you post and answer

Comment: MAT stands for a mixing temperature of air streams and OAT stands for outside air temperature...its more mechanical engineering topics. Epsilon or E is a value of 2 and 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless something really weird is going on, then yes that is an absolute value. Interestingly, there seems to be a typo on the other side of the inequality. I imagine they meant: $\sqrt{\varepsilon\mathrm{MAT}^2+\varepsilon\mathrm{OAT}^2}$.